# Angular - RxJS : afterViewInit and Async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I tried to do the following in my component which uses   `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,`

```
@ViewChild('searchInput') input: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.searchText$ = fromEvent<any>(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map(event => event.target.value),
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );
}
```

And in the template

```
<div *ngIf="searchText$ | async as searchText;">
  results for "<b>{{searchText}}</b>"
</div>
```

It doesn't work, however if I remove the `OnPush`, it does. I am not too sure why since the async pipe is supposed to trigger the change detection.

**Edit**:

Following the answers, I have tried to replace what I have by the following:

```
this.searchText$ = interval(1000);
```

Without any `@Input`, the `async` pipe is marking my component for check and it works just fine. So I don't get why I haven't got the same behavior with the `fromEvent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Whenever Angular kicks change detection, it goes through all components one by one and checks if something changes and updates its DOM if it's so. what happens when you change default change detection to `ChangeDetection.OnPush`?

Angular changes its behavior and there are only two ways to update component DOM.

- @Input property reference changed
- Manually called markForCheck()

If you do one of those, it will update DOM accordingly. in your case you don't use the first option, so you have to use the second one and call `markForCheck()`, anywhere. but there is one occasion, whenever you use async pipe, it will call this method for you.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe **marks the component to be checked for changes**. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

so there is nothing magic here, it calls `markForCheck()` under the hood. but if it's so why doesn't your solution work? In order to answer this question let's dive in into the AsyncPipe itself. if we inspect the source code AsyncPipes transform function looks like this

```
transform(obj: Observable<any>|Promise<any>|null|undefined): any {
    if (!this._obj) {
      if (obj) {
        this._subscribe(obj);
      }
      this._latestReturnedValue = this._latestValue;
      return this._latestValue;
    }
    ....// some extra code here not interesting
 }
```

so if the value passed is not undefined, it will subscribe to that observable and act accordingly (call `markForCheck()`, whenever value emits)

**Now it's the most crucial part**
the first time Angular calls the transform method, it is undefined, because you initialize `searchText$` inside `ngAfterViewInit()` callback (the View is already rendered, so it calls async pipe also). So when you initialize `searchText$` field, the change detection already finished for this component, so it doesn't know that `searchText$` has been defined, and subsequently it doesn't call AsyncPipe anymore, so the problem is that it never get's to AsyncPipe to subscribe on those changes, what you have to do is call `markForCheck()` only once after the initialization, Angular ran changeDetection again on that component, update the DOM and call AsyncPipe, which will subscribe to that observable

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.searchText$ =
     fromEvent<any>(this.input.nativeElement, "keyup").pipe(
      map((event) => event.target.value),
      startWith(""),
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    this.cf.markForCheck();
  }
```

Comment: I am very confused, I really shouldn't have to do that, the async pipe should be marking the component for Check.
Without any Input, if I create a interval(1000) and async pipe on it, my template is getting updated with the OnPush

Comment: So you mean using interval, instead of fromevent?

Comment: are y sure that it's working?, because It's should be the same I think I'll test it

Comment: this.searchText$ = interval(1000)
      .pipe(map(() => this.input.nativeElement.value))
      .pipe(startWith(""), debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged());   //Thats the code right?

Comment: I just had this.searchText$ = interval(1000)  when I did the test

Comment: quite confusing though it doesn't work still, and It should not work definitely, because there is no difference between interval and fromEvent on this perspective

Comment: @Scipion , I finally found the answer and I'll update it. great question though :P

Answer (score 1):

The `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` allow to the component to not triggered the changeDetection all the time but just when an @Input() reference is updated. So if you do all your stuff in the same component, no @Input() reference are updated so the view is not updated.

I propose you to Create your dumb component with your template code above, but give it the searchText via an @Input(), and call your dumb component in your smart component

**Smart component**

```
<my-dumb-component [searchText]="searchText$ | async"></my-dumb-component>
```

**Dumb component**

```
@Input() searchText: SearchText
```

template

```
<div *ngIf="searchText">
  results for "<b>{{searchText}}</b>"
</div>
```

Comment: I have no doubt it would work, however I shouldn't have to do that. From my understanding the async pipe inside the component should do the work.
https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: The issue here is not the async pipe but the changeDetection, because no input reference is updated, it's why the changeDetection is specially used for dumb component and not smart component, if you don't want to change your structure, you must remove the changeDetection onpush. 
In your post, the smart-dumb component are used, and angular push for this structure

Answer (score 0):

This is because Angular is updates DOM interpolations before **ngAfterViewInit** and **ngAfterViewChecked**. I know this sounds confusing a bit. It's because of the first change detection cycle Angular does. Referring to [Max Koretskyi's article about change detection algorithm of Angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular), in a change detection cycle these happens sequentially:

1. sets ViewState.firstCheck to true if a view is checked for the first time and to false if it was already checked before
2. checks and updates input properties on a child component/directive
   instance
3. updates child view change detection state (part of change detection
   strategy implementation)
4. runs change detection for the embedded views (repeats the steps in
   the list)
5. calls OnChanges lifecycle hook on a child component if bindings
   changed
6. calls OnInit and ngDoCheck on a child component (OnInit is called
   only during first check)
7. updates ContentChildren query list on a child view component
   instance
8. calls AfterContentInit and AfterContentChecked lifecycle hooks on
   child component instance (AfterContentInit is called only during
   first check)
9. updates DOM interpolations for the current view if properties on
   current view component instance changed
10. runs change detection for a child view (repeats the steps in this
    list)
11. updates ViewChildren query list on the current view component
    instance
12. calls AfterViewInit and AfterViewChecked lifecycle hooks on child
    component instance (AfterViewInit is called only during first
    check)
13. disables checks for the current view (part of change detection
    strategy implementation)

As you see, Angular updates DOM interpolations (at step 9) after **AfterContentInit** and **AfterContentChecked** hooks are called, so if you call rxjs subscriptions in **AfterContentInit** or **AfterContentChecked** lifecycle hooks (or earlier, like OnInit etc.) your DOM will be updated because Angular updates DOM at step 10, and when you change something in ngAfterViewInit() and you are using OnPush, Angular won't update DOM because you are at step 12 on ngAfterViewInit() and Angular has already updated DOM before you change something!

There are workaround solutions to avoid this to subscribe it in ngAfterViewInit. First, you can call markForCheck() function, so you basically say by using it on the first cycle that "hey Angular, you updated DOM on step 9, but I have something to change at step 12, so please be careful, have a look at ngAfterViewInit I have still something to change". Or as a second solution, you can trigger a change detection manually again (by triggering and event handler or using detecthanges() function of ChangeDetectorRef) so that Angular repeats all these steps again, and when it reaches at step 9 again, Angular updates your DOM.

I have created a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changedtc-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that you can try these out. You can uncomment the lines of subscriptions placed in lifecycle hooks 1 by 1, so that you can see after which lifecycle hook Angular updates DOM. Or you can try triggering an event or triggering change detection cycle manually and see that Angular updates DOM on the next cycle.